# C convert unsigned char array to float array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting, dereference

Is there a way to convert unsigned char array to float array without dereferencing each element of uchar array?

```
unsigned char* arr1 = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 3);
float* arr2 = malloc(sizeof(float) * 3);

*arr1 = 3;
*(arr1 + 1) = 55;
*(arr1 + 2) = 213;

*arr2 = (float)(*arr1); // 3.0
*(arr2 + 1) = (float)(*(arr1 + 1)); // 55.0
*(arr2 + 2) = (float)(*(arr1 + 2)); // 213.0
```

Comment: You can (and *should*) use `arr1[i]` and `arr2[i]` notation rather than `*(arr1 + i)`; and you can use a `for` loop to reduce the amount of code. And `arr2[i] = arr1[i];` will do the cast *implicitly*.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) arr2[i] = arr1[i];`

Comment: There is no other way. If you are looking for some `memcpy` -style solution - there is none.

Comment: Any solution that results in the `float` elements containing the `unsigned char` values must tell the compiler to get the values from the `unsigned char` elements in one way or another. You cannot get values without getting values. Possibly you could do it in bulk with SIMD operations rather than individually for each element. Other than that, what could you mean?